# After e-filing an I-130, is this all I need to concurrently file the I-145?

Tags: usa, immigration

I previously filed an I-130 online. To file successfully an I-485, as of 2022-08-21, it seems like I need

- [I-864ez](https://www.uscis.gov/i-864ez): Affidavit of Support Under Section 213A of the INA (or some I-864 form)
- [I-485 Fee](https://www.uscis.gov/i-485), different for everyone for me $1,225
- [I-485: Application to Register Permanent Residence or Adjust Status](https://www.uscis.gov/i-485) (Green Card form)

  - FREE [I-765: Application for Employment Authorization](https://www.uscis.gov/i-754) (which is free with I-485), has
  - FREE [I-131: Application for Travel Document](https://www.uscis.gov/i-131) (which is free with I-765)

Still have to do this, but it says we're better to wait.

- [I-693, Report of Medical Examination and Vaccination Record](https://www.uscis.gov/i-693)

I also think I need to file with this evidence, as petitioner,

- Me

  - Birth Certificate
  - Passport
  - Financial information
  - Three years copy of my Tax Returns (which [TurboTax may suffice])
  - Three years copy of W-2's
- Marriage Certificate
- Spouse's

  - Income tax records for proof of continuous residence.
  - Birth Certificate
  - Passport
  - Evidence of Continuously Maintaining a Lawful Status Since Arrival in the United States

Comment: Just follow the checklist in the instructions.

Comment: Also, I-693 is not required to be filed together with I-485, but if you don't - interview is a must. If you do - the USCIS may end up waiving interview entirely. See the "When to File" section.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, read the I-485 instructions. It seems like you are missing the following from I-485:

- I-130 receipt
- two passport-style photos of the beneficiary
- I-94 as evidence of admission

You don't need:

- marriage certificate
- petitioner's birth certificate or passport
- evidence of maintaining status (since you are in the Immediate Relative category)

In addition, the other forms you are filing also require their own documents. I-765 needs:

- A copy of the beneficiary's last EAD (if they ever got one) or another government ID (if not)
- two passport-style photos of the beneficiary

And I-131 needs:

- photo ID of the beneficiary
- I-94 to show present status
- two passport-style photos of the beneficiary

I see that you already included tax returns for the I-864 (one year is required, three years is optional). It is also recommended to include a few months of recent pay stubs as evidence of your current income. An employer letter would be extra helpful. For the tax returns, it is often simpler to use IRS tax return transcripts, because then you don't need to include all the tax schedules and W-2s/1099s, but if there's not enough time to get the IRS tax return transcripts, then a copy of the tax returns, with all schedules and W-2s/1099s, is fine.